# catch cmd output and include it on list java

Tags: java, android

i try to do some cmd command in java, my script:

```
public void test(){
try{

Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec("cmd /c "+"adb devices");

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while((line=input.readLine())!=null){

    System.out.print(line);

}

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("process failed");
    }
}
```

and the output result:

```
run:
List of devices attached 
0160880B0401F006    device
```

how can i catch the part of that result: "0160880B0401F006" and put into a list on my gui?

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [a regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (untested):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\d+)\s*(.*)");
while((line=input.readLine())!=null){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String id = matcher.group(1);
        String name = matcher.group(2);
        // do whatever you want with your values here
        System.out.println("id: " + id + ", name: " + name);
    }
}
```

You should also read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), in case you run into any problems with executing the external command.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void test(){
        try{

            Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = rt.exec("cmd /c "+"adb devices");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line=input.readLine();//discard first line
            List<String> deviceList=new ArrayList<String>();
            while((line=input.readLine())!=null){
                deviceList.add(line.split(" ")[0]);
            }
            System.out.println("Device list "+deviceList);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("process failed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i try to use your method. but its show error at this line:
 List<String> DeviceList=new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: what is the error? If it is related to imports add 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;